# Quitting Xcode 8 and reopening it breaks constraints in my Xib file

Tags: xcode

encountering a very frustrating issue. I have a Xib file for my custom UITableViewCell. I set the constraints up and there are no warning or issues and the app runs fine. However if I close the Xcode and reopen it they are set to different values and the entire view is broken.

[image]

There seems to be no way to fix this, even if I reset to a previous commit the view remains broken. Has anyone else encountered this? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Please try Xcode 8.1 which addresses the following:

Xcode 8.0 did not always restore view frames from storyboards and xibs when layouts were ambiguous. Xcode 8.1 fixes several of these issues. If you have encountered these issues, resolve the ambiguity in the Auto Layout issues and update frames. Xcode 8.1 will persist them correctly. (28221021, 28244619)

(If not, please file a bug with http://bugreport.apple.com.)